# How to use laravel's pagination with an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

I have a button that when clicked loads data from my database via an ajax request.

```
<button id="btn_test">Load All Records</button>

<div id="all_rec"> </div>
```

The content is loaded into the `div` element dynamically. With many rows it would make sense to use pagination here not only for a faster response time but a more user friendly feel. Thus I would like to know if there is a way to use laravel's pagination in this case.

N.B When I used laravel's pagination, I got the first set of records(first page) to load properly but when I clicked page 2 nothing showed up on the screen.

Comment: The page button needs to send another ajax request with the link provided by Laravel's pagination.

Comment: You just need to use the link from laravel pagination, use it as url for ajax req